# Как установить boost версии больше 1.65.1, при установке стандартными командами не получается поставить версию выше

Tags: c++, linux, docker, cmake, boost

поставил буст в докере через комманды

```
libboost-dev \
libboost-program-options-dev \
libgtest-dev
```

Но он установил boost версии 1.65.1, как можно обновить его до более новой версии буста? Мне нужна 1.68 минимум.

Comment: собрать ручками или использовать образ с более свежей убунтой

Comment: Никак, если ставите из пакетов, то извольте пользоваться старьем. Если хочется новее - делайте изолированную утановку и/или используйте контейнер.

Comment: проверил на последней убунте - 1.74 - что достаточно новое.

Comment: @KoVadim у меня в докере 18.04 убунта, блин, придется видимо руками

Comment: если что, 18 - это значит, что она 2018 года. а сегодня уже как минимум 2021:)

Comment: А главное - в вопросе нет указания ни об используемом дистрибутиве, ни его версии.

Comment: ну так это легко можно догадаться. Ну вряд ли человек в докере будет использовать slackware или Getntoo. Скорее всего убунту, дебиан или альпайн. По именам пакетов остается два варианта.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Установил в докере вот таким образом:

```
RUN cd /home && wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.68.0/boost_1_68_0.tar.gz \
      && tar xfz boost_1_68_0.tar.gz \
      && rm boost_1_68_0.tar.gz \
      && cd boost_1_68_0 \
      && ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local --with-libraries=program_options \
      && ./b2 install
```